# X-Editable Adding Grouping to Drop Down Menu

Tags: php, x-editable

I have made a dropdown box using X-Editable. Works well but I wanted to add grouping and this is where I ran into problems.

I can add the first group called Western but every time I add a second group the code fails. Has anyone got an example of adding extra grouping and children?

```
$('#booking_data').editable({
container: 'body',
selector: 'td.map5',
url: "update.php",
title: 'Map5',
type: "POST",
dataType: 'json',
source:
[
    {text: "Western", children:
        [
            {value: "T1-Bordeaux", text: "T1-Bordeaux"},
            {value: "T1-Grenoble", text: "T1-Grenoble"},
            {value: "T1-Gronigen", text: "T1-Gronigan"},
            {value: "T1-Le Mans", text: "T1-Le Mans"},
            {value: "T1-Rennes", text: "T1-Rennes"}
        ]
    }
],

validate: function(value){
if($.trim(value) == '')
{
return 'This field is required';
}
}
 });

  This produces this dropdown but I need a group of Central and Eastern too.
```

[Existing Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bKL4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved: It took ages to get the syntax correct but in case anyone is interested here is the solution:

```
source:
[
{text: "Western-T1", children:
    [ 
        {value: "T1-Bordeaux", text: "T1-Bordeaux"},
        {value: "T1-Grenoble", text: "T1-Grenoble"},
        {value: "T1-Gronigen", text: "T1-Gronigan"},
        {value: "T1-Le Mans", text: "T1-Le Mans"},
        {value: "T1-Rennes", text: "T1-Rennes"}
    ]
},
{text: "Central-T1", children:
    [
        {value: "T1-Polask", text: "T1-Polask"},
        {value: "T1-Slutsk", text: "T1-Slutsk"},
        {value: "T1-Kursk", text: "T1-Kursk"},
        {value: "T1-Korocha", text: "T1-Korocha"},
        {value: "T1-Kyiv", text: "T1-Kyiv"}
    ]
},
 {text: "Eastern-T1", children:
    [
        {value: "T1-Sovietsk", text: "T1-Sovietsk"},
        {value: "T1-Urzhum", text: "T1-Urzhum"},
        {value: "T1-Kostroma", text: "T1-Kostroma"},
        {value: "T1-Yelnat", text: "T1-Yelnat"},
        {value: "T1-Zhirnov", text: "T1-Zhirnov"}
    ]
},
```